# how to create blender 2.90 addons folder?

Tags: installation

how to get blender 2.90 to install and use the "roaming" path? I'd like to copy the content of 2.91 to 2.90 and have 2.90 see everything from that folder.
C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender
currently it only has this path:
C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender-2.90\2.90\scripts

the 2.91 path has config and scripts folders with all the custom addons and startup info.
C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.91

Comment: I didn't test this but I think if you delete the 2.90 folder, and rename the 2.91 to 2.83 it should prompt you to import the settings from this folder the first time you open 2.90 again (backup before doing this of course)

Comment: Is there any reason why you can’t just copy and paste the one from 2.91 into 2.90 directory?

Comment: the point is 2.90 does not goto the 'Roaming path' by default.I've not had this issue before and not sure how to get blender 2.90 to default to it.

Comment: @Gorgious  that did work, but i had to install from the blender msi